# Cross-Browser. Como añadirlo a mi página Web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy realizando un trabajo para clase y me piden que realice **Cross-Browser**.
¿Cómo añado eso exactamente a mi página web? Estoy trabajando con HTML, CSS y JS.

Comment: `Cross-Browser` se refiere a que funcione en cualquier navegador, aunque la tendencia es dar soporte solo a navegadores recientes: Firefox, Chrome (y sus derivados: Opera, Edge, etc.) y Safari. Entonces, solo debes asegurarte de que tu proyecto funcione en los navegadores que te especifiquen.